Binary sparse irreducible/tridiagonal matrix with dense inverse?
I'd like to construct a distribution to generate sparse binary matrices with dense inverse, and I see this question When is the inverse of a sparse matrix dense?, which mentioned in the comment that "irreducible matrices have generally dense inverses" and in the answer that "unconnected components of the graph" can be exploited to get "uncoupled blocks". And in the comment I get the useful information that tridiagonal matrix can have dense inverse. But there is little information online about binary field.
I really want to know more details about binary case. Could someone help to provide some more info about this? Is it possible to obtain such a distribution of binary matrices through irreducible  matrix or any other structures?
Thanks so much for any instructions or corrections.

That answer claims "a tridiagonal matrix will generally have a fully dense inverse" which seems like an answer to your question - unless I misunderstand what you're asking for?

@MishaLavrov Thanks for your comment! But does this rule still work on the binary field with finite field operation?

This is trickier to say; over $\mathbb R$, we can choose random entries to get a non-singular tridiagonal matrix with probability $1$, but over a finite field, we can't. I tried something out just now: a distribution of random tridiagonal matrices over $\mathbb F_2$ with random entries on the main diagonal and $1$'s immediately above and below it. Out of $100$ tries of $1000\times1000$ matrices, $66$ were non-singular (i.e. odd determinant), and their inverses over $\mathbb F_2$ had an average density of $44.3%$. Of course, all of this is experimental, not proof.

Thanks for your efforts @MishaLavrov, your experiment provides good inspiration. I will collect more info online, and probably do some experiments myself!
